# Trouble installing factory_boy with pip

Tags: python, django, pip, factory-boy

I'm working on a Django project. I'm setting up my environment on another machine and when I run `pip install factory_boy`, I get the following traceback:

https://gist.github.com/JSweetman/35f59536d6b87a0ce8c0

Does anyone know what's happening? I installed `factory_boy` in a different environment on the same machine and it worked so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: your setuptools version seems to be lower than required.What os are you using?

Comment: For output that short, I'd suggest you include it in your question next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update `setuptools`. Like so:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

and then

```
pip install factory_boy
```

should work. `sudo` may be required in front of those commands depending on your os and setup, but if you're using a virtualenv it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you! I literally just found that out as you commented it and was going to try to answer my question but I am restricted for being a new user. I appreciate the fast answer though!

Comment: Lol, glad it helped. If you want some starting rep and advice for being a new user, if an answer helped you, you should "accept" it by pressing the green arrow under the up/downvotes.