# After installing factory_boy, imports are not recognized.

Tags: django, pip, factory-boy

Pip install factory_boy seems to install the package without problems. Running pip freeze shows me:

```
Django==1.7
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
factory-boy==2.4.1
gunicorn==19.1.1
static3==0.5.1
```

However, when I edit my tests to put import factory or import factory.django... I get the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\Projects\gamematch2\eventbook\tests.py", line 6, in <modul
e>
    import factory.django
ImportError: No module named factory.django
```

I've followed the advice in:
[Trouble installing factory_boy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771274/trouble-installing-factory-boy-with-pip/23771326#23771326)
with no results.

Not sure how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you just do `import factory` ? if you still face errors, it means the installation was not successful

Comment: Importing factory fails too. >>> import factory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named factory
>>>

Comment: so thats the issue. Have you installed factoryboy inside a virtualenv, and forgot to activate it while executing?

Comment: What is this "activate it while executing"? That sounds like exactly the problem, but I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a problem with my virtual environment. Exiting virtualenv, installing factory_boy again, and then running manage.py test again works successfully. Not fully solved, but at least I have a work around.